# What is right order for defining decorators in django views

Tags: python, django, django-views, decorator, python-decorators

I want to set more than one decorator for my django function view. The problem is that I can't figure out how should be the order of decorators.

For example this is the view I have:

```
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@api_view(["POST"])
def logout(request):
    pass
```

In this case, first decorator never applies! neither when request is POST nor when it's GET!

When I change the order, to this:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def logout(request):
    pass
```

the last decorator applies before the first one, which is not the order that I want.

I want the decorator `@api_view(["POST"])` to be applied first, and then `@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])`.

How should I do that?

Comment: I don't know if it matters but in [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) they use the second option. Why do you want them to be applied in different order?

Comment: Please don't use FBV for DRF, internally it creates a class-based view, but it is not a good idea to stretch it to a function anyway. Especially since authorization, etc. are a lot more complicated in a Django REST view.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Actually it works that way, but I don't figure out, why it can't be implemented vice versa! I thinks It's more logical the other way.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah! It seems so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way of ordering 'api_view' consider the view as API view that the decorator is defined by restframework.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes

@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def logout(request):
    pass
```

Comment: Actually it works that way, but I don't figure out, why it can't be implemented vice versa! I thinks It's more logical the other way.

Comment: @api_view(["POST"]) decorator is used to consider this view as restframework api view .othervise this is conside as normal view that case we need csrf_token to inside with post method